# maximum call stack size exceeded in local database data fetch in for loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, callstack, stack-size

I am using  awiat in for loop 2 times for data fetching from local database.
Apparently it works fine but when I open and close the screen/component 4-5 times .It shows me the error. "Maximum call Stack size Exceeded"

I Have tried many solutions like promises to handle it but it still it gives me this error.

code :
for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
console.log('batchno', val[i].batchno);
let result = await item.GetPendingCountwithbatchno(val[i].batchno); //from sqllite
let result2 = await item.GetCalledphoneNumberCountswithbatchno(
val[i].batchno,
); // from sql lite

```
  let pending = result.rows.item(0).Cnt;
  let called = result2.rows.item(0).Cnt;
  val[i].pending = pending;
  val[i].called = called;
}
console.log('val:', val);
console.log('lastindex:', lastindex);
//return val;
if (val[lastindex].pending != undefined) setbatchlist([...val]);
```

};

Comment: Can you post the code of your whole component?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi Yess Sure       https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WdTXcJUOnYeM3MbYtcUKB4cadMRvaVcQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are not unsubscribing your calls in useEffect, so each time the component is mounted all calls get executed. You need to unsubscribe the calls in your useEffect return function